# How to query a reference table for a value between a dates for a specified category in Apps Script?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a background in data analytics and have done a similar workflow in SQL but am brand new to Apps Script. I am a bit at a loss on where to even start in Apps Script. Any advice or pointing me in the direction of useful examples would be truly appreciated!

Currently, I have a reference table on one sheet with categories and values and the start and end date that value applies to. Then I have a data table on another sheet where I add an entry date and a category and I would like to have Apps Script write the corresponding value for that category on the date.

Reference table data (a blank end date means that is the current rate):

| Category | Value | Start date | End date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25 | 01/01/2022 | 3/31/2022 |
| B | 40 | 01/01/2022 |  |
| C | 30 | 01/01/2022 |  |
| A | 15 | 04/01/2022 |  |

The data table where the entry date and the category are added manually over time. I want to use the reference table to write the value for that category for that entry date.

| Entry Date | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/20/2022 | B | ***40*** |
| 02/27/2022 | A | ***25*** |
| 03/20/2022 | A | ***25*** |
| 04/16/2022 | C | ***15*** |
| 05/12/2022 | A | ***30*** |
| 06/02/2022 | B | ***40*** |

How do you get the query the reference data for that entry date and category to find the row with the corresponding value?

Comment: Why apps script? You can do this with  formula like  `=vlookup()` or if you're familiar with sql, you'll love `=query()`.

Comment: I think your result table is incorrect.  It should be C 30, A 15.  And I agree with TheMaster although I'm not good at QUERY, it should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

As I said I'm not good at QUERY but I finally got something to work.  I'm sure other can improve on it.

First I created a named range `TestQuery` for the table of data.  I could have just as easily used range "A1:D6"

Next I fill in the End Date with `=TODAY()` so it has a date value.  Then I build my query.

```
=QUERY(TestQuery,"select B where ( ( A = '"&B11&"' ) and ( date '"&TEXT(A11,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' > C ) and ( date '"&TEXT(A11,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' < D ) )")
```

[image]

**Reference**

- [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [Compare Dates in Query](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting data from a table on a sheet

```
function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const values = sh.getRange("A2:D" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values));//2d array
}
```

A2 is assumed to be the upper left corner of the data